# limit bucket size google cloud storage

Tags: cloud, google-cloud-storage

is there any limit in bucket size in Google Cloud storage? I would like to store 4 petabytes of data in 4 different buckets.

I have read the documentation in detail and I only see that there is a 5TB limit per file.

It would be great is someone could confirm that the buckets have no limit

regards,
mikel

Comment: Confirmed that there is no limit, but can you explain what limitations you would like to impose and why?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to configure a max size on data that can be stored in a bucket. One possibility would be to have a staging bucket where data get uploaded, with [Object Change Notifications](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification) configured, and an app (running either in App Engine or Compute Engine) that receives those notifications, tracks how much data is currently in the bucket, and either copies the data to the 'real' bucket in the same location (so the copy operations are handled without byte copying, just metadata operations) or rejects the upload.