# How to add space to google storage bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I created storage bucket, but there is no option to specify its storage size, while `gsutil du -s` indicates only 32Mb available.

Comment: `du` lists the *used* space of your bucket, not the total available space. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/du

Comment: Hi @CoryKramer, how would one determine total capacity of a bucket?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46244957/limit-bucket-size-google-cloud-storage

Comment: The buckets have unlimited storage capacity. You are charged by used space https://cloud.google.com/storage#section-10

Comment: Only your money limit the cloud storage. Ask apple on it: https://appleinsider.com/articles/21/06/29/apple-is-now-googles-largest-corporate-customer-for-cloud-storage

Answer (score 5):

Google Cloud Storage buckets do not have a limited size, you can just keep adding objects forever. There are [other limits](https://cloud.google.com/storage/quotas), however, such as *individual* objects must be <= 5TiB.

If you intend to upload truly vast amounts of data (e.g. petabytes of storage, or tbps upload rates) you should probably reach out to Google via sales channels to make sure there is capacity, and because you can probably negotiate discounts.