# Is there any way to limit the amount of the number of pictures inserted in to firestore bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am working on a feature in my app that allow the user to add up to 20 images to storage … but not more that that I will implement a front end limit but I want to do this in security rules as well .. images go under the user uid, the issue here is how to get control over the images file in bucket so it can have only 20 pics ? similar to an array.size or map.size ?

```js
// storageRef
const storageRef = ref(storage,`images/${currentUser?.uid}/{imgId}`);

// Rules
match /images/{userId}/{img} {      
     // Add to Storage     
      allow write:  
      if isAuthed() &&
      request.resource.size < 524288 &&//Size
      request.resource.contentType.matches('image/.*'); // Type
   }
}
```

Comment: It's not possible with security rules alone.  You will need to keep track using some other GCP products, or make them upload through a method other than directly from the client app.

Comment: Looks like you need to hack a solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46244957/limit-bucket-size-google-cloud-storage

Comment: @DougStevenson I have no issue with using an increment in firestore doc ... but if I want to increment from client but if someone wants to throw a wrench at it they could put any number instead of increment is there any way it can be done in a secure way ?

Comment: Read through the duplicates to get some ideas.